# Mint cinnamon doesn't load after hibernation

Tags: hibernate, linux-mint, cinnamon

From the time I installed mint 13 (cinnamon) I cant hibernate and resume correctly  .  every time when i do `pm-hibernate` the system hibernates  but when i resume   cinnamon is not loaded ,  the icons and all are a mesh  and if i try to restart cinnamon the system freezes (same if i try to do cinnamon --replace on a terminal).

I have plenty of swap (10GB and my ram is only 2GB)

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2013       1773        240          0         20        356
-/+ buffers/cache:       1396        616
Swap:        10313        255      10058
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't state your hardware details, only a generic answer is possible. I'd guess some part of your hardware is causing trouble on suspend/resume, as it is often the case (some video-drivers are know for that). That's where `SUSPEND_MODULES` kicks in: modules defined here are unloaded on suspend, and reloaded on resume -- so concerning the problematic hardware it looks like shutdown/startup. To give you one reference: [Here is one thread on the Linux Mint forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=141&t=58746) dealing with similar trouble on a Sony Vaio, and [here's another dealing with sdhci causing trouble on a HP Pavilion](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=96303). These are just examples, you will find many more on a search for "SUSPEND_MODULES", best with some hardware specs (hint: some wifi hardware also often is the cause for this kind of trouble, same applies to graphics and tv-cards).